# how to make checkbox using angular + ionicframework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a checkbox on popover.

I am able to make popover on button click but the checkbox does not display when the user selects an option. I want to show [this](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png) image when the user selects an option.

The user can select multiple option with as many checbboxes. To show the checkbox I overwrite it's css.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6MR6TvCYnWnnsD6B8nh?p=preview)

```
 .checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px; /* Removed padding to eliminate color bleeding around image
       you could make the image wider on the right to get the padding back */
    background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ionic [ion-checkbox directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/)

Here's edited plunkr and edited popover template  http://plnkr.co/edit/Pglgc4lAqfwVuPYmVGac?p=preview

```
<script id="my-popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-popover-view>
        <ion-header-bar>
            <h1 class="title">My Popover Title</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in a track by item.name">
                <ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked">{{item.name}}</ion-checkbox>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-popover-view>
</script>
```

If you still want to use custom icon dont forget to toggle the class of element for example by using [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: how I will use ng-class which could directive